# How to change directories in Linux with Docker

Tags: java, linux, docker

My code is working but I can't change directories using the command. I can ls,touch, etc... but I can't cd.

In this case `message` is the command I want. ex: ls

What is this fix for this?

```
public static String getDockerConsole(String containerName, String message) {
    String[] cmd = new String[]{
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            message
    };
    DockerClient dockerClient = dockerClient();
    Container container = getContainer(containerName);
    ExecCreateCmdResponse execCreateCmdResponse = dockerClient.execCreateCmd(container.getId()).withAttachStdout(true).withTty(true).withAttachStderr(true).withCmd(cmd).withUser("root").exec();
    ByteArrayOutputStream  out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream err = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        dockerClient.execStartCmd(container.getId()).withExecId(execCreateCmdResponse.getId()).withTty(true).exec(new ExecStartResultCallback(out, err)).awaitCompletion();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return out.toString() + err.toString();
```

Comment: What is even stranger is that if I cd to a directory that doesn't exist it shows me the error that doesn't exist.

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to `cd` within a Java application running inside of a Docker container, and that isn't working? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: No errors. It works if I ls /dirName. But what I actually want is to change folders

Comment: Could you try to chain the commands, like `message = "cd someDir && ls"` ?

Comment: ok I will check

Comment: it works....... But how do I execute a file in that dir? I needed something like cd dir && ./file

Answer (score 1):

When ExecCreateCmdResponse is executed with the message 'cd folder', a process is created connected to a tty that executes sh and makes the change to the new folder, but it proccess dies. As it dies, if you run again the sh will return to the home folder.

Try for example cd and ls in the same command sh processes:

```
message = "cd /bin; ls ; cd /var; ls"
```

Comment: My point is to run a file. When I run it it goes to background instead of showing. cd /folder;./dn

Comment: But why does it die? Can't I just keep the connection open and keep sending commands?

Comment: The problem may be with collecting std and err outputs.

Make sure the program has run:
run java with message below:
    message =    'cd /folder;./dn > output 2> error'
on terminal outside java:
    docker exec CONTAINER /bin/sh -c 'cat /folder/output; cat /folder/error'

Comment: When I call `dockerClient.execStartCmd(container.getId()).withExecId(execCreateCmdResponse.getId()).withTty(true).exec(new ExecStartResultCallback(out, err)).awaitCompletion();` it sends the process to background and hangs here but I can see the console I just can't interact.

Comment: The process ends because this is not an interactive process. When a non-interactive process ends it naturally dies.

Comment: How do I make it interactive? I can't use System.in because this is a web app console not command line. I want to make a console like this:  https://portainer.io/overview.html

Comment: The approach would be a bit different. What you need is to execute a sh (or bash) in interative mode (e.g. when use -i in docker on terminal) and somehow get the user to interact with it. And do not execute a sh for each user command.